# Infinite loop with .Find method

Tags: vba, excel, find, format, infinite-loop

I am trying to write a VBA script to automate moving things around in an spreadsheet that has a balance sheet imported from an accounting software. 
The values on imported balance sheet start at row 5, column A has some text describing what the values of each row mean, and columns B and D have the amounts for each item.

The subtotals for each section and subsection of the balance sheet are on columns C and E. Each subtotal has is in a cell formatted with a solid upper border.

I would like to bring all these subtotals to the same columns as the values (i.e, columns B and D). I've tried to do this using the .Find method to search for cells with the specific format (cells with an upper border) and a Do loop to keep searching until I find all cells that should have a subtotal in it.

Notes:

1. I didn't use FindNext because it seems that it ignores format settings used in the preceding Find method, as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/282151).
2. I tried to used the [FindAll function described by Tushar Mehta](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1001%20range.find%20and%20findall.shtml#_Using_the_SearchFormat) to go around this problem with FindNext, but it didn't find all cells with the specified format.

Here's the code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub FixBalanceSheet()
  Dim LookFor As Range
  Dim FoundHere As String 'Address of the cell that should contain a subtotal
  Dim beginAt As Range, endAt As Range, rng As Range 'Set the ranges for the sum to get the subtotal
  Dim place As String 'String with the address of a cell that will contain a subtotal
  Dim WhereToLook As Range 'Range where subtotals are to be found

  'Set workbook and worksheet
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set WhereToLook = Range("A5:F100")
    'Every cell containing a subtotal has an upper border. So, look for cells containing border!
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    'Call search using .Find
    Set LookFor = WhereToLook.Find(What:="", After:=Cells(5, 2), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not LookFor Is Nothing Then 'Test if a cell with a bottom border is found
      'What happens when a subtotal cell is found:
      FoundHere = LookFor.Address
      Debug.Print "Found at: " & Found
      'Loop to set a range, sum values and put them in the right cell
      Do
       '% find out a range to calculate subtotals and put the value in the right cells  %'
        'Call for next search
        With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Set LookFor = WhereToLook.Find(What:="", After:=endAt, SearchFormat:=True)
        Debug.Print "LookFor now is: " & LookFor.Address
        Rem If LookFor.Address = Found Then ' Do not allow wrapped search
          Rem Exit Do
        Rem End If
      Loop Until LookFor Is Nothing Or LookFor.Address = FoundHere ' Do not allow wrapped search
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't reassigned endAt to be LookFor during each subsequent search...

Comment: Right Flephal, that's how he knows he's at the end/staring spot.

Comment: Thanks Flephal, that was what was causing the infinit loop!

Comment: It didn't find all cells with the border, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a range object to loop through your range. You can add a total if you need a grand total, but this is probably an easier way than trying to select all cells that have formatting.

For example:

```
Sub TestStackOverflowCode()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rngToChk As Range

    'This is where you'd insert WhereToLook
    Set rngToChk = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B4")

    For Each r In rngToChk

        'If the top edge does not NOT have a border
        If r.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            'Copy the cell value to two cells to the right
            r.Offset(, 2).Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going back to the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)/[Range.FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx). There were some holes in your logic conditions and I believe I've adjusted them.

```
Set LookFor = WhereToLook.Find(What:="", After:=Cells(5, 2), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)
If Not LookFor Is Nothing Then 'Test if a cell with a bottom border is found
  'What happens when a subtotal cell is found:
  FoundHere = LookFor.Address
  Debug.Print "Found at: " & FoundHere
  'Loop to set a range, sum values and put them in the right cell
  Do

   'do something with LookFor as a Range Object here

    'Call for next search
    Set LookFor = WhereToLook.FindNext(After:=LookFor)   '<~~ look for next after current cell
    Debug.Print "LookFor now is: " & LookFor.Address
  Loop Until LookFor.Address = FoundHere ' Do not allow wrapped search (LookFor will never be nothing here)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The findNext may not have worked if

- you had [FindFormat.Borders...] after the [Set LookFor = WhereToLook.Find(...]

I do think ThreeTrickPony's answer is more elegant, but in general I'd suggest finding an alternative way to identify cells rather than formatting.